# How to send efficiently a data array over udp between c++ and java

Tags: java, c++, arrays, udp, double

I am going to send a double array over udp socket. I am using Winsock library in c++ on the Clinet side and java on the server side. My current idea is to make a string out of this double numeric data and send. However I feel it is not appropriate and need the conversion in both sides to the numeric values. How I can send this data more efficiently?

I tried the following but received error "argument of type "double *" is incompatible with parameter of type "const char *" in sendto() function"

```
double arrayTosend[100] 

int sendOk = sendto(out, arrayToSend, sizeof(arrayToSend), 0, (sockaddr*)&server, sizeof(server));
```

Comment: Note: You can't send raw `double` unless the other machine uses an identical architecture. If you do want to send raw values, cast them to an array of bytes (`const char*`) as noted in the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use [Google's Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) for handling the transfer of your array:

- It is a solid mechanism for serializing/deserializing messages between remote and internal processes.
- It is easy to use and learn.
- It will generate the required code for getting and receiving the array on both your c++ and java processes.
- If you change your array to a different type, or decide to transfer additional information - the message format used by protocol buffer will allow you to change your transferred data easily and will regenerate all the required boilerplate code.